# Table showing each JQueryMobile version and its compatibility with JQuery versions?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, compatibility

Given that JQueryMobile uses JQuery, I'm looking for a definitive table that lists JQueryMobile versions and which earliest and latest versions of JQuery they can use.

To my great surprise [JqueryMobile.com](http://jquerymobile.com) does *not* seem to have this table, except for the latest version of JQueryMobile and what it is paired with, on the site front landing page.

People will want to use JQueryMobile earlier versions for a number of good reasons, e.g. if there is regression in later versions, other compatibility issues or just not ready to move up to the latest version (risks to project for example).

Comment: jQM 1.x -> jQ 1.6.x / jQM 1.2.x -> jQ 1.8.x / jQM 1.3.x & 1.4.x -> jQ 1.9.x

Comment: jQM 1.4.5 -> jQ 2.1.4

Comment: jQM 1.5.0 -> jQ 3.0.0