# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I added jQuery's swipleLeft and swipeRight to a couple of pages of mine to be able to use a swipeable navigation menu. After I did so, whenever I click on a link within my navigation, I get the following error when getting to that page:

```
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

All I added was `jQuery 1.10.2.min.js`, `jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js`, and the jquery.mobile css stylesheet.

This error is causing my formatting to go out of wack. The only time the error comes up and affects the style of the page is when I get to the page via the navigation. If I type the page url into the browser and go to it that way, it is fine. Before I added these scripts the navigation links worked as normal.

Anyone know why I would be getting this error?

In head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Before the closing body tag:

```
$(function(){
  $( "body" ).on( "swiperight", swiperightHandler );

  function swiperightHandler( event ){
    $('.nav-panel').addClass( "swiperight" );
  }
});
$(function(){
  $( "body" ).on( "swipeleft", swipeleftHandler );

  function swipeleftHandler( event ){
    $('.nav-panel').removeClass( "swiperight" );
  }
});
$.mobile.loading().hide();
```

Comment: The later version jQuery is just warning you that you have an `async: false` used somewhere. Find (and kill) that evil little pest first :)

Comment: Q: Why do you have 2 different version of jQuery. Try drop the old one (if possible).

Comment: I don't get where the error would be. The code I put in my question is all the new code I have added. Whenever I remove  `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` the swipeable menu no longer works.

Comment: That probably means that swipeable is not compatible with jQuery 1.10.2. Best test that component in isolation and see if you have to scrap/replace it.

Comment: @GoneCoding It works with 1.10.2 though? It doesn't work with just 3.1.1 and the mobile alone.

Comment: The console source is pointing at the error being right here: `):l.open(n.type,n.url,n.async),n.xhrFields`

Comment: What swipeable menu you are using? Just for the sake of completeness, JQuery Mobile has already swipeable panels [Open Panel on swipe](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-swipe-open/#demo-page)

Comment: @deblocker I am just using the swipeleft and swiperight functions. I believe the error has to do with `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` , but I am not sure why.

Comment: @GoneCoding: i just upvoted your catch, but for the opposite reason: jQuery Mobile 1.4.5 is compatible with jQuery 1.8 - 1.11 / 2.1. See also there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098811/table-showing-each-jquerymobile-version-and-its-compatibility-with-jquery-versio - Why not use Panels? They solves all the swipe problems with no-code.

Comment: I changed it to the 2.1 version, but it still has that notice. This error is effecting the style on my pages when I click on the nav links. I do not get why.